# accepts_nested_attributes_for :reject_if to trigger another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I've got a multi-level nested form using formtastic_cocoon (jquery version of formtastic).

I am trying to do some validation in the sense of

```
if value is_numeric do
     insert into database
else do
     database lookup on text
     insert id as association
end
```

I was hoping tha the accepts_nested_attributes_for would have an :if option, but apparently there is only the :reject_if.

Is there a way to create a validation like I describe as part of the accepts_nested_attributes_for??

-----------------------Updated as per Zubin's Response ---------------------------

I believe Zubin is on the right track with a method, but I can't seem to get it working just right. The method I am using is

```
    def lookup_prereq=(lookup_prereq)
        return if lookup_prereq.blank?
            case lookup_prereq
        when lookup_prereq.is_a?(Numeric) == true
            self.task_id = lookup_prereq
        else
            self.task = Task.find_by_title(lookup_prereq)
        end
    end
```

When I trigger this function, the self.task_id is being put in the database as '0' rather than the Task.id.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something else. 
I'm not completely sure that the method is actually being called. Shouldn't I need to say

```
lookup_prereq(attr[:prereq_id)
```

at some point?

-------------------further edit -----------------------
I think from what I can find that the method is called only if it is named with the same name as the value for the database, therefore I've changed the method to

```
def completed_task=(completed_task)
```

Unfortunately this is still resulting in 0 as the value in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a method in your nested model to handle that, eg:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :author

  def lookup_author=(lookup_author)
    return if lookup_author.blank?
    case lookup_author
    when /^\d+$/
      self.author_id = lookup_author
    else
      self.author = Author.find_by_name(lookup_author)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Zubin, I think this is VERY close to what I'm looking for, but I don't seem to be getting it to work just right. I've updated the question with your code, adapted to do what I'm looking for, but for some reason, I'm not getting the look-up find_by_task returning the correct id, and the database is always getting 0. You deserve the points for getting the right answer, I think, but I can't really tell if the method is being run properly.